# Page not loading content - Body archive - page

Tags: posts, pages

I'm working on this [page](http://oleart.es/tienda/)

The problem Is that is not loading any content, altought it's english version does: [link](http://oleart.es/en/oleart-catologue/)

I'm not getting any console errors so can't find where the problem is.

[image]

The only difference I see is that the spanish page has :

```
<body class="page page-id-584 page-template page-template-tienda-page-php logged-in admin-bar woocommerce woocommerce-page customize-support">
```

and the english version has :

```
<body class="archive post-type-archive post-type-archive-product logged-in admin-bar woocommerce woocommerce-page customize-support">
```

It is exactly the same page, just translated to english, any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Are you using a translator plugin?

Comment: yes, WPML. The strange thing is that the spanish page, which is the original did has before the archive body classes (and it was working before), but it changed to page body class without me doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset your permalink from admin site. you may get page if there is a conflation with permalink.